# Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I'm attempting upgrade from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 and am experiencing the following exception:

> Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=3.1.8.0,

In my .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And my ConfigureServices method:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);
            services.AddSignalR();

            //Configure Abp and Dependency Injection
            return services.AddAbp<AppLibraryBuilderWebFrontEndModule>(options =>
            {
                //Configure Log4Net logging
                options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
                    f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
                );
            });
        }
```

I'm aware services.AddMvc() is no longer supported in .NET Core 3.1 but could someone please suggest how I can migrate the existing setup?

Comment: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />` looks odd if you are on 3.1.

Comment: Very true, thanks for pointing that out! I presume since this is no longer supported the correct thing to do is to remove that line, but this doesn't affect the initial error message.

Comment: Well, I'd expect the version number to be different at the very least.

Comment: 2.2 is the highest available version on NuGet, which is why I suggested removing rather than updating to a higher version.

Comment: As you said, you want to upgrade your project to 3.1, however, the highest version in your visual studio is 2.2, so you need to download the `3.1 SDK`, you can download in your `visual studio installer ` or download in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=netcore31